# gsub escaped double quote to an escaped single quote in string

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following input string:

```
string = "\"Newegg.com\" <Promo@email.newegg.com>"
```

I want to replace the `\"` with `\'`. I tried this:

```
string.gsub(/\"/) {|i| "\\'" }
# => "\\'Newegg.com\\' <Promo@email.newegg.com>"

string.gsub(/\"/,%q(\\\'))
# => "\\'Newegg.com\\' <Promo@email.newegg.com>"
```

In both ways, it actually has two instances of `\`, but I want only one. It seems to be an issue with the backslash and escaping b/c this works otherwise:

```
string.gsub(/\"/,%q('))
# => "'Newegg.com' <Promo@email.newegg.com>"
```

-- Update 1--
yes, puts does display the "correct" value

```
temp = string.gsub(/\"/,%q(\\\'))
# => "\\'Newegg.com\\' <Promo@email.newegg.com>"
puts temp
# >> \'Newegg.com\' <Promo@email.newegg.com>
```

but I want to store this exact value displayed on the last line.

Comment: It's usually easier to look at string results with `puts` because then the output doesn't include escaping. It gets confusing fast.

Comment: Hey @GarrettMotzner, yes the `puts` does display \'Newegg.com\' <Promo@email.newegg.com>... but I want to store this exact value.

Comment: By "store this exact value displayed on the last line" do you mean "store the value with the quotes and stuff added by inspect"?

Comment: thanks @GarrettMotzner, that helped. Looks like another field in the stored values is the actual issue after I broke it down more as per your below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual string doesn't include `\`

```
puts "\"Newegg.com\" <Promo@email.newegg.com>"
> "Newegg.com" <Promo@email.newegg.com>
```

This will replace `"` with `'` as you wished:

```
puts "\"Newegg.com\" <Promo@email.newegg.com>".gsub('"', "'")
> 'Newegg.com' <Promo@email.newegg.com>
```

If you really wanted `\"`, try another escape character like:

```
puts "\\\"Newegg.com\\\" <Promo@email.newegg.com>"
> \"Newegg.com\" <Promo@email.newegg.com>
```

Same replace should work:

```
puts "\\\"Newegg.com\\\" <Promo@email.newegg.com>".gsub('"', "'")
> \'Newegg.com\' <Promo@email.newegg.com>
```

Comment: thanks, @lenin. See Update 1. I don't want to display... I want to store that output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your getting a bit confused (understandably so) by the returned result.
Keep in mind that in irb, the last result is formatted using `.inspect`, which means that it wraps strings in double quotes, and then escapes characters (backslashes and double quotes)' that would need to be escaped in a double quoted string. This is to distinguish between strings and other values such as numbers, arrays, hashes, etc.

However, that is just the result of inspect. if you use puts to output the value, it will output it without any escaping - it is a more accurate representation of your value.The value displayed by puts is the real value, and what would be stored if you saved the value to a variable.

If you still can't tell what your string looks like, try this:

```
temp = string.gsub(/\"/,%q(\\\'))

temp.split('')
=> ["\\", "'", "N", "e", "w", "e", "g", "g", ".", "c", "o", "m", "\\", "'", " ", "<", "P", "r", "o", "m", "o", "@", "e", "m", "a", "i", "l", ".", "n", "e", "w", "e", "g", "g", ".", "c", "o", "m", ">"]
```

This explodes your string into an array of single characters, and can make it easier to see exactly what is in your string. Notice you have a `\` character (displayed as `"\\"`, but since each string is guaranteed to be exactly one character long, you know it is being displayed that way because of inspect) and a `'` character at the beginning.